# check the width and height of an image

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

i am trying to check the width and height of an image in a directory by using python . the directory consist of two folders and each folder there are pictures want to check the width and height to resize them if they are not matched. here is my code:

```
def Resize(imageFolder, factor_1, factor_2):


    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(imageFolder):
       for fileName in files:

         image = Image.open(fileName)
         image_size = image.size
         width = image_size[0]
         height = image_size[1]
         if ((width and height) == 224):
            print("the width and height are equals")

            continue
         print("the width and height are not equals, so we should resize it")    
        resize_pic(path, fileName, factor_1, factor_2)
```

when I run the code gives me error, i think the loop is not right. any help ?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "resize.py", line 62, in <module>
 Resize(imageFolder, resizeFactor , resizeFactor_h)

 File "resize.py", line 46, in Resize
   image = Image.open(fileName)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2028, in open

 raise IOError("cannot identify image file")

 IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Comment: Well what is `fileName` when that error gets thrown?

Comment: it should be the image

Comment: *"should be"* - did you bother to find out? Do some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)!

Comment: i am new in python, i will try to do some debugging

Comment: Try `Image.open(os.path.join(path, fileName))`...

Comment: @ Rawing  I have tried it also I got the same error

Comment: Are you sure those files are in fact valid images that can be read by Python? (Using what library?) (Also, not entirely sure about that `if` line - but it's unrelated to the current error message.)

Comment: yes valid images with extention of (.bgm). and according to Libraries that i used are : import os
import sys
import Image
from PIL import Image . and i dont think the problem from condition, it's just from fileName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (pth, dirs, files) in os.walk(imageFolder):
    for fileName in files:
        image = Image.open(fileName)
        with Image.open(os.path.join(pth, fileName)) as image:
            image_size = image.size
```

You need provide the absolute path of the file as well like above.

Also check on image file format